# how to declare a structure with large structure arrays inside it

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define     MAXNO   1000

typedef struct
{
    int     n;
    char    site[4];
} stru;

typedef struct
{
    stru t1[MAXNO];
    stru t2[MAXNO];
} struall;

int main()
{
    struall tmp;
    int i;
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 1;
}
```

Hi everyone, I am trying to declare a structure variable which has two structure array members inside it. If the array size (MAXNO) is small, i can compile successfully. However, if the array size is very large (define MAXNO as 1000000), the declaration fails with segmentation fault.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read a little bit about [stack and heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: `C` and `C++` are separate languages. Tag sensibly.

Comment: @sjsam You right but reason for this problem is the same in both languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can only fit "oh-so-much" onto the machine stack. Try:

```
struall* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struall));
```

in C or one of the following for C++:

```
struall* tmp = new struall; // C++03
std::unique_ptr<struall> tmp{new struall}; // C++11
auto tmp = std::make_unique<struall>(); // C++14
```

Comment: Nice and complete :-) A bit of explanation about each method will give you a fanbase for this one I guess..nbd though..